# Reducing time by using OpenMP parallelization

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I'm trying to reduce the computation-time of my algorithm by using OpenMP parallelization (C++).
I tried simple things, but I don't quite understand how it works...

Here is my code:

```
int nthread = omp_get_max_threads();
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthread)
for(int i=0;i<24;++i)
  std::cout << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
```

On my computer, nthread = 6. I don't understand why the output is:

```
0
0
0
... (24 times)
```

Why doesn't it give my numbers from 0 to 5 ?

If I understand it well (correct me if I'm wrong), in this code, there are 6 threads which will execute the std::cout command.
Then, why do I have only "0" as an output ?

Second thing: I would like to execute in each thread a certain part of the loop. I want to divide my loop in 6 (nthread) different parts, so that each can be executed by a different thread.

Here, I want each of my 6 threads to execute

```
std::cout << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
```

4 times.

How can I do it? I tried this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthread)
for(int i=omp_get_thread_num()*(24/nthread);i<(omp_get_thread_num()+1)*(24/nthread);++i)
  std::cout << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
```

Is it right? The output I have is:

```
0
0
0
0
```

Is it normal to have only the "0" thread and no other in the terminal?

Thank you

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to use OpenMP or would you be open to use concurrency functionality of the C++ standard library? More people would be able to help in that case.

Comment: Make sure you are turning on OpenMP, a pragma is something the compiler can ignore and it means nothing if you don't have /openmp.

Read the following, and tip #1 is what I am guessing your problem is: http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0054/#ID0EQAAE

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer but I couldn't stay silent on this

> I tried this:

```
for(int i=omp_get_thread_num()*(24/nthread);i<(omp_get_thread_num()+1)*(24/nthread);++i)
  std::cout << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
```

> Is it right?

No, it's not right, not right at all !  The code is doing the work of dividing iterations across threads, a better model to follow would be

```
for(int i=0;i<max_iters;++i)
  do work depending on i
```

and the compiler/run-time will take care of dividing the work across threads.  Each thread will get its own set of values of `i` to work on.

This simple pattern is only correct if each task inside the loop is independent of every other task, so no dependencies between `work(i)` and `work(i-1)` say.  But at the beginning that's probably enough to get you started.

As for the rest of your question it looks as if you aren't actually running the code in parallel.  I suggest replacing

```
int nthread = omp_get_max_threads();
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(nthread)
```

with

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

that is, leave the number of threads to the default set up.  If that doesn't work, edit your question with the results of your further investigations.  And have a look round at SO, I'm fairly sure that you'll find a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

RyanP, you were absolutely right, I missed the keyword openmp.
I added it and now it works well! Thanks a lot.

Also thank you High Performance Mark for your answer,

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

was enough for what I wanted to do.

I knew that

```
for(int i=omp_get_thread_num()*(24/nthread);i<(omp_get_thread_num()+1)*(24/nthread);++i)
  std::cout << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
```

was wrong, but since the other things I tried didn't work, I tried insane things. Thanks for your explanation, it's clearer now.

To resolve my problem, I simply add to my CMakeList.txt the following lines:

```
find_package(OpenMP)
if (OPENMP_FOUND)
    set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
    set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
endif()
```

And it works well.

Thank you all